# How to detect if a changelist deletes a branch in a classic Perforce depot

Tags: perforce

I have a classic Perforce depot. Given is a list of directories where each directory represents a branch. Is there any way to detect if a given changelist deletes **all** files in the branch (and therefore deletes the entire branch)?

E.g:

```
//depot/branch1
//depot/branch2
```

I tried: `p4 sync -n //depot/branch1/...@<CHANGELIST>` to sync the entire branch. `-n` is to simulate, or to preview, a sync. But the returned output doesn't help me. Is there any other option how to detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help files

    files -- List files in the depot

    p4 files [ -a ] [ -A ] [ -e ] [-i] [ -m max ] file[revRange] ...

        ...

        The -e flag displays files with an action of anything other than
        deleted, purged or archived.  Typically this revision is always
        available to sync or integrate from.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 files dir/...
//stream/main/dir/bar#2 - delete change 119 (text)
//stream/main/dir/foo#2 - delete change 119 (text)

C:\Perforce\test>p4 files -e dir/...
dir/... - no such file(s).
```

So do:

```
p4 files -e //depot/branch1/...
```

If it says `no such file(s)` then everything in that directory has been deleted.

If you want to check the state as of a certain submitted changelist, just add the changelist as a revision specifier:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 files -e dir/...@119
dir/...@119 - no such file(s).

C:\Perforce\test>p4 files -e dir/...@118
//stream/main/dir/bar#1 - add change 106 (text)
//stream/main/dir/foo#1 - add change 106 (text)
```

In this example we can tell that change `@119` specifically was the one to delete the directory because at that changelist files don't exist, but at the prior one they do.

---

This works the same way in a stream depot:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 switch foo

C:\Perforce\test>p4 files ...
//stream/foo/dir/bar#2 - delete change 131 (text)
//stream/foo/dir/foo#2 - delete change 131 (text)

C:\Perforce\test>p4 files -e ...
... - no such file(s).
```